# VBA / How to check if item of dictionary exists in another dictionary?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I need to have two dictionaries in VBA and i would like to check if one item of first dictionary exists in the second one. I tried the code below but it doesn't find the item. Only message "not exist" appears. Can someone help?

```
Sub Dict()

Dim Tuna As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Tuna = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Pako As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Pako = New Scripting.Dictionary

Tuna.Add "01", "first"
Tuna.Add "02", "second"

Pako.Add "01", "first"

If Tuna.Exists(Pako.Items(0)) = True Then
MsgBox ("exists")
Else
MsgBox ("not exists")

End If
End Sub
```

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.exists()` function checks if a `key` exists. You are searching for an `item` so you will need to use a loop and check each item in the dictionary.

For example:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim item As Variant  
    Dim Tuna As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Pako As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set Pako = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Tuna = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Tuna.Add "01", "first"
    Tuna.Add "02", "second"
    Pako.Add "01", "first"

    For each item in Tuna.Items
        If item = Pako("01") Then

            ' do something

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate an array from the items of one dictionary and use Match to see if contains a specific value (not as nice as `.Exists` but just for S&G)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Dict()
    Dim Tuna As Scripting.Dictionary, Pako As Scripting.Dictionary, tunaArray
    Set Tuna = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Pako = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Tuna.Add "01", "first"
    Tuna.Add "02", "second"

    Pako.Add "01", "first"
    ReDim tunaArray(0 To Tuna.Count - 1)
    tunaArray = Tuna.Items

    If Not IsError(Application.match(Pako.Items(0), tunaArray, 0)) Then
        MsgBox "exists"
    Else
        MsgBox "not exists"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kubie points out, `Exists` checks for keys rather than values. If you have a 1-1 correspondence between values and keys, you could maintain two dictionaries, one for the keys to values mapping and one for the values to keys inverse mapping:

```
Sub Dict()

    Dim Tuna As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Tuna = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim TunaItems As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set TunaItems = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Pako As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Pako = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Tuna.Add "01", "first"
    TunaItems.Add "first", "01"
    Tuna.Add "02", "second"
    TunaItems.Add "second", "02"

    Pako.Add "01", "first"

    If TunaItems.Exists(Pako.Items(0)) = True Then
        MsgBox ("exists") 'works as expected
    Else
        MsgBox ("not exists")
    End If
End Sub
```

If the correspondence isn't one-to-one, you could have the values in the second dictionary be e.g. the first key which leads to a given value. It would of course be up to you to make sure that the two dictionaries stay in sync.